# how to fix release apk Assertion failed in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

it's my first time uploading flutter application to google play 
and I did all the steps in the flutter.io guide 
my application is working like a charm in debugging mode so I Created a Keystore and Reference it 
as well as Configured signing in Gradle
but finally when I run

```
flutter build apk --release
```

or

```
flutter run --release
```

below errors appear

```
Unhandled exception: Assertion failed.
assertx (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/utils.dart:34:5)
SummaryCollector.crea teSummary (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/summary_collector.dart:331:5)
TypeFlowAnalysis.getSummary (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:1408:52)
DirectInvocation._processFunction (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:240:42)    
_DirectInvocation.process (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:174:14)
_WorkList.processInvocation (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:1294:32)
 _WorkList.process (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:1274:7)
TypeFlowAnalysis.process (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:1421:14)
transformComponent (package:vm/transformations/type_flow/transformer.dart:70:20)
_runGlobalTransformations (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:381:5) <asynchronous suspension>
compileToKernel (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:300:11) <asynchronous suspension>
FrontendCompiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (package:vm/frontend_server.d art:383:56)
new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:176:37)  
_rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
_CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
_Cust omZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
_CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
_CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
_CustomZone.bindCallbac k.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:21:15)
_Timer._runTim ers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
_Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
_RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
> Compiler terminated unexpectedly.
```

what to do to fix them?

P.s. `my flutter doctor -v`

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows
>   [Version 10.0.18362.267], locale en-US)    • Flutter version
>   1.9.1+hotfix.4 at C:\Users\t.ghassan\flutter
>       • Framework revision cc949a8e8b (9 weeks ago), 2019-09-27 15:04:59 -0700
>       • Engine revision b863200c37
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 29.0.2)
>       • Android SDK at C:\Users\t.ghassan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
>       • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
>       • All Android licenses accepted. [√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
>       • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
>       • Flutter plugin version 29.0.1
>       • Dart plugin version 173.4700
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.40.1)
>       • VS Code at C:\Users\t.ghassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
>       • Flutter extension version 3.6.0
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
>       • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5556 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
>
> • No issues found!